# Splitting an array dynamically based on values using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dynamic, split

I'm trying to find an easier way of splitting an array dynamically based on values of an inner array within a JSON object.

Assume that I am receiving said data from OpenWeatherAPI:

```js
 var jsonData={  
    "cod":"200",
    "message":0.0895,
    "cnt":5,
    "list":[  
      {  
         "dt":1512388800,
         "main":{  
            "temp":301.9,
            "temp_min":299.858,
            "temp_max":301.9,
            "pressure":1017.53,
            "sea_level":1020.58,
            "grnd_level":1017.53,
            "humidity":98,
            "temp_kf":2.04
         },
         "weather":[  
            {  
               "id":803,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"broken clouds",
               "icon":"04n"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{  
            "all":80
         },
         "wind":{  
            "speed":2.36,
            "deg":161.003
         },
         "rain":{  

         },
         "sys":{  
            "pod":"n"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2017-12-04 12:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "dt":1512399600,
         "main":{  
            "temp":300.75,
            "temp_min":299.389,
            "temp_max":300.75,
            "pressure":1019.04,
            "sea_level":1022.09,
            "grnd_level":1019.04,
            "humidity":100,
            "temp_kf":1.36
         },
         "weather":[  
            {  
               "id":803,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"broken clouds",
               "icon":"04n"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{  
            "all":68
         },
         "wind":{  
            "speed":2.04,
            "deg":133.002
         },
         "rain":{  

         },
         "sys":{  
            "pod":"n"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2017-12-04 15:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "dt":1512410400,
         "main":{  
            "temp":299.41,
            "temp_min":298.726,
            "temp_max":299.41,
            "pressure":1017.89,
            "sea_level":1020.93,
            "grnd_level":1017.89,
            "humidity":100,
            "temp_kf":0.68
         },
         "weather":[  
            {  
               "id":801,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"few clouds",
               "icon":"02n"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{  
            "all":24
         },
         "wind":{  
            "speed":2.08,
            "deg":108.001
         },
         "rain":{  

         },
         "sys":{  
            "pod":"n"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2017-12-04 18:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "dt":1512421200,
         "main":{  
            "temp":298.19,
            "temp_min":298.19,
            "temp_max":298.19,
            "pressure":1017.39,
            "sea_level":1020.45,
            "grnd_level":1017.39,
            "humidity":100,
            "temp_kf":0
         },
         "weather":[  
            {  
               "id":801,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"few clouds",
               "icon":"02n"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{  
            "all":24
         },
         "wind":{  
            "speed":2.26,
            "deg":94.0002
         },
         "rain":{  

         },
         "sys":{  
            "pod":"n"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2017-12-04 21:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "dt":1512432000,
         "main":{  
            "temp":298.444,
            "temp_min":298.444,
            "temp_max":298.444,
            "pressure":1019.32,
            "sea_level":1022.39,
            "grnd_level":1019.32,
            "humidity":100,
            "temp_kf":0
         },
         "weather":[  
            {  
               "id":801,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"few clouds",
               "icon":"02d"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{  
            "all":20
         },
         "wind":{  
            "speed":2.5,
            "deg":89.0016
         },
         "rain":{  

         },
         "sys":{  
            "pod":"d"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2017-12-05 00:00:00"
      }
    ],
    "city":{  
      "id":1735158,
      "name":"Petaling Jaya",
      "coord":{  
         "lat":3.1073,
         "lon":101.6067
      },
      "country":"MY"
     }
    }

 $.each(jsonData['list'], function(index, value) {

              $.each(value, function(index, value){
                if(index == 'dt_txt')
                {
                    var regExDate = new RegExp('^.{0,10}');
                    value = regExDate.exec(value).toString();
                    console.log(value);
                }
              });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How do I iterate the elements in `list` to split based on `dt_txt`?

This is pretty much as far as I got to manually convert the dates into YYYY-MM-DD format but I'm still struggling to make a dynamic array based out of the results that I'm getting:

Result:

[image: My result for the code above]

**EDIT #1**:

The end result I'm looking for should look something like this:

```
var array20171204 = [{"dt":1512388800,"main":{"temp":301.9,"temp_min":299.858,"temp_max":301.9,"pressure":1017.53,"sea_level":1020.58,"grnd_level":1017.53,"humidity":98,"temp_kf":2.04},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":80},"wind":{"speed":2.36,"deg":161.003},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2017-12-04 12:00:00"},{"dt":1512399600,"main":{"temp":300.75,"temp_min":299.389,"temp_max":300.75,"pressure":1019.04,"sea_level":1022.09,"grnd_level":1019.04,"humidity":100,"temp_kf":1.36},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"clouds":{"all":68},"wind":{"speed":2.04,"deg":133.002},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2017-12-04 15:00:00"},{"dt":1512410400,"main":{"temp":299.41,"temp_min":298.726,"temp_max":299.41,"pressure":1017.89,"sea_level":1020.93,"grnd_level":1017.89,"humidity":100,"temp_kf":0.68},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02n"}],"clouds":{"all":24},"wind":{"speed":2.08,"deg":108.001},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2017-12-04 18:00:00"},{"dt":1512421200,"main":{"temp":298.19,"temp_min":298.19,"temp_max":298.19,"pressure":1017.39,"sea_level":1020.45,"grnd_level":1017.39,"humidity":100,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02n"}],"clouds":{"all":24},"wind":{"speed":2.26,"deg":94.0002},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2017-12-04 21:00:00"}];

var array20171205 = [{"dt":1512432000,"main":{"temp":298.444,"temp_min":298.444,"temp_max":298.444,"pressure":1019.32,"sea_level":1022.39,"grnd_level":1019.32,"humidity":100,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],"clouds":{"all":20},"wind":{"speed":2.5,"deg":89.0016},"rain":{},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2017-12-05 00:00:00"}];
```

Comment: Could you specify how the final result should look like? Your question is confusing and seems to missed the main point. Also you can just use a library to parse the dates instead, or just use `new Date()`

Comment: `I'm still struggling to make a dynamic array` - Please describe what the array suppose to look like. This can be as simple as `var arr = []; arr.push(<someRandomData>)` but without knowing what final array structure you are looking for it's hard to guess.

Comment: Hi. I've added some edits to clarify some doubts on my expected result. Note that the name of the variables are generated as per the value of `dt_time`.

Consequently, if we can dynamically generate 2D array based on date against data, this would solve the problem of having to generate variables to hold X number of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the question completely but is this what you were looking for:

```
var arr=[];
var list = jsonData['list'];
list.filter(function(item) {
    var temp = item.dt_txt.split(" ")[0];
    arr.push({[temp]: item});
});
```

Comment: Hi. This is rather accurate. However, I am trying understand the part in which you are pushing it in arr. Does [temp] : item act a as a key/value pair when inserting into the array?

Comment: Yes exactly, since the key of the object is a variable we enclosed it in square brackets

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt create dynamic variable name; besides that this code does handles the other aspects;

```js
var jsonData={  
    "cod":"200",
    "message":0.0895,
    "cnt":5,
    "list":[  
      {  
         "dt":1512388800,
         "main":{  
            "temp":301.9,
            "temp_min":299.858,
            "temp_max":301.9,
            "pressure":1017.53,
            "sea_level":1020.58,
            "grnd_level":1017.53,
            "humidity":98,
            "temp_kf":2.04
         },
         "weather":[  
            {  
               "id":803,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"broken clouds",
               "icon":"04n"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{  
            "all":80
         },
         "wind":{  
            "speed":2.36,
            "deg":161.003
         },
         "rain":{  

         },
         "sys":{  
            "pod":"n"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2017-12-04 12:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "dt":1512399600,
         "main":{  
            "temp":300.75,
            "temp_min":299.389,
            "temp_max":300.75,
            "pressure":1019.04,
            "sea_level":1022.09,
            "grnd_level":1019.04,
            "humidity":100,
            "temp_kf":1.36
         },
         "weather":[  
            {  
               "id":803,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"broken clouds",
               "icon":"04n"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{  
            "all":68
         },
         "wind":{  
            "speed":2.04,
            "deg":133.002
         },
         "rain":{  

         },
         "sys":{  
            "pod":"n"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2017-12-04 15:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "dt":1512410400,
         "main":{  
            "temp":299.41,
            "temp_min":298.726,
            "temp_max":299.41,
            "pressure":1017.89,
            "sea_level":1020.93,
            "grnd_level":1017.89,
            "humidity":100,
            "temp_kf":0.68
         },
         "weather":[  
            {  
               "id":801,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"few clouds",
               "icon":"02n"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{  
            "all":24
         },
         "wind":{  
            "speed":2.08,
            "deg":108.001
         },
         "rain":{  

         },
         "sys":{  
            "pod":"n"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2017-12-04 18:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "dt":1512421200,
         "main":{  
            "temp":298.19,
            "temp_min":298.19,
            "temp_max":298.19,
            "pressure":1017.39,
            "sea_level":1020.45,
            "grnd_level":1017.39,
            "humidity":100,
            "temp_kf":0
         },
         "weather":[  
            {  
               "id":801,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"few clouds",
               "icon":"02n"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{  
            "all":24
         },
         "wind":{  
            "speed":2.26,
            "deg":94.0002
         },
         "rain":{  

         },
         "sys":{  
            "pod":"n"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2017-12-04 21:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "dt":1512432000,
         "main":{  
            "temp":298.444,
            "temp_min":298.444,
            "temp_max":298.444,
            "pressure":1019.32,
            "sea_level":1022.39,
            "grnd_level":1019.32,
            "humidity":100,
            "temp_kf":0
         },
         "weather":[  
            {  
               "id":801,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"few clouds",
               "icon":"02d"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{  
            "all":20
         },
         "wind":{  
            "speed":2.5,
            "deg":89.0016
         },
         "rain":{  

         },
         "sys":{  
            "pod":"d"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2017-12-05 00:00:00"
      }
    ],
    "city":{  
      "id":1735158,
      "name":"Petaling Jaya",
      "coord":{  
         "lat":3.1073,
         "lon":101.6067
      },
      "country":"MY"
     }
    }

let dtArray = [];
jsonData["list"].map((obj) => {
   let dt = obj["dt_txt"].split(" ")[0]
   if(dtArray.indexOf(dt) == -1) {
      dtArray.push(dt)
   }
});
let tempArray;
for(i=0 ;i<dtArray.length; i++) {
   //let array+str(date) = [];
   tempArray = [];
   jsonData["list"].map((obj) => {
      if(dtArray[i] == obj["dt_txt"].split(" ")[0]) {
         tempArray.push(obj)
      }
   });
   console.log(tempArray)
}
```